unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log is no longer written since upgrade to 24.04
I have enabled unattended upgrades since a long time on my systems.
Before I upgraded two systems from Kubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, I would usually see an additional entry in /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log, when a reboot was done after a system upgrade or when the system was manually rebooted:
2024-04-19 05:34:46,130 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running

If the upgrade was still running, this would be mentioned as well.
After upgrading to 24.04, unattended upgrades are still running fine.
/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log and
/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
show both that upgrades are being applied as expected at the time I have configured. Only reboots are no longer documented as before.
My /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades:
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";

My /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades:
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
//
// Note that in Ubuntu security updates may pull in new dependencies
// from non-security sources (e.g. chromium). By allowing the release
// pocket these get automatically pulled in.
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
    // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
    // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
    // should also install from here by default.
    "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
    "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};

// Python regular expressions, matching packages to exclude from upgrading
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    // The following matches all packages starting with linux-
//  "linux-";

    // Use $ to explicitely define the end of a package name. Without
    // the $, "libc6" would match all of them.
//  "libc6$";
//  "libc6-dev$";
//  "libc6-i686$";

    // Special characters need escaping
//  "libstdc\+\+6$";

    // The following matches packages like xen-system-amd64, xen-utils-4.1,
    // xenstore-utils and libxenstore3.0
//  "(lib)?xen(store)?";

    // For more information about Python regular expressions, see
    // https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
};

// This option controls whether the development release of Ubuntu will be
// upgraded automatically. Valid values are "true", "false", and "auto".
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "false";

// This option allows you to control if on a unclean dpkg exit
// unattended-upgrades will automatically run 
//   dpkg --force-confold --configure -a
// The default is true, to ensure updates keep getting installed
Unattended-Upgrade::AutoFixInterruptedDpkg "true";

// Split the upgrade into the smallest possible chunks so that
// they can be interrupted with SIGTERM. This makes the upgrade
// a bit slower but it has the benefit that shutdown while a upgrade
// is running is possible (with a small delay)
//Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";

// Install all updates when the machine is shutting down
// instead of doing it in the background while the machine is running.
// This will (obviously) make shutdown slower.
// Unattended-upgrades increases logind's InhibitDelayMaxSec to 30s.
// This allows more time for unattended-upgrades to shut down gracefully
// or even install a few packages in InstallOnShutdown mode, but is still a
// big step back from the 30 minutes allowed for InstallOnShutdown previously.
// Users enabling InstallOnShutdown mode are advised to increase
// InhibitDelayMaxSec even further, possibly to 30 minutes.
// Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "false";

// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed. E.g. "user@example.com"
// Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "";

// Set this value to one of:
//    "always", "only-on-error" or "on-change"
// If this is not set, then any legacy MailOnlyOnError (boolean) value
// is used to chose between "only-on-error" and "on-change"
// Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "on-change";

// Remove unused automatically installed kernel-related packages
// (kernel images, kernel headers and kernel version locked tools).
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";

// Do automatic removal of newly unused dependencies after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies "true";

// Do automatic removal of unused packages after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";

// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if
//  the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";

// Automatically reboot even if there are users currently logged in
// when Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot is set to true
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers "true";

// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "now";

// Use apt bandwidth limit feature, this example limits the download
// speed to 70kb/sec
// Acquire::http::Dl-Limit "70";

// Enable logging to syslog. Default is False
Unattended-Upgrade::SyslogEnable "false";

// Specify syslog facility. Default is daemon
Unattended-Upgrade::SyslogFacility "daemon";

// Download and install upgrades only on AC power
// (i.e. skip or gracefully stop updates on battery)
// Unattended-Upgrade::OnlyOnACPower "true";

// Download and install upgrades only on non-metered connection
// (i.e. skip or gracefully stop updates on a metered connection)
// Unattended-Upgrade::Skip-Updates-On-Metered-Connections "true";

// Verbose logging
// Unattended-Upgrade::Verbose "true";

// Print debugging information both in unattended-upgrades and
// in unattended-upgrade-shutdown
// Unattended-Upgrade::Debug "false";

// Allow package downgrade if Pin-Priority exceeds 1000
// Unattended-Upgrade::Allow-downgrade "false";

// When APT fails to mark a package to be upgraded or installed try adjusting
// candidates of related packages to help APT's resolver in finding a solution
// where the package can be upgraded or installed.
// This is a workaround until APT's resolver is fixed to always find a
// solution if it exists. (See Debian bug #711128.)
// The fallback is enabled by default, except on Debian's sid release because
// uninstallable packages are frequent there.
// Disabling the fallback speeds up unattended-upgrades when there are
// uninstallable packages at the expense of rarely keeping back packages which
// could be upgraded or installed.
// Unattended-Upgrade::Allow-APT-Mark-Fallback "true";

DPkg::Options {
        "--force-confold";
        "--force-confdef";
};

What am I missing?
What do I have to set to see those unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log entries again?

@David DE - I just noticed you made changes to my post. To your personal taste. Stop that. NOT wanted. Reverted to V1.
